# Count by date range between min date and max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to return a count by date range between min date and max date for projects.
My table contains:

| RecordID | ProjectID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1254879 | 00025 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 1254248 | 00025 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1253598 | 00025 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1253578 | 00025 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 1253698 | 00025 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 1254873 | 00025 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 1253697 | 00259 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 1253570 | 00259 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 1254999 | 00037 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 |
| 1252695 | 00037 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 1254889 | 00037 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 |

The expected result is:

| ProjectID | Sequence | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00025 | 01 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 00025 | 02 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 00025 | 02 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 00025 | 03 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 00025 | 03 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 00025 | 03 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 00259 | 01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 00259 | 01 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 00037 | 01 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-31 |
| 00037 | 02 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 00037 | 03 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 |

I tried some queries and the most complex query that I've used without success was:

```
select 
    ProjectID
    ,count(1) as Sequence
    ,min(StartDate) as StartDate
    ,max(EndDate) as EndDate
from(
    select 
        t.*
        ,row_number() over(order by EndDate) as sequence
        ,row_number() over(partition by RecordID order by EndDate) as sequence_t
    from 
        dbo.ProjectTable as t
) as t
group by
    ProjectID
    ,(sequence - sequence_t)
order by
    min(EndDate)
```

I don't know how to return the expected value in sequence once count in this query and other queries that I tried return only 1 for each record.

Below the DDL

Create Table:

```
create table [dbo].[ProjectTable](
    [RecordID] int NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] int NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] date NULL,
    [EndDate] date NULL 
) on [primary]
go
```

Insert Data:

```
insert into [dbo].[ProjectTable] values
    (1254879,00025,'2021-01-01','2021-02-28'),
    (1254248,00025,'2021-03-01','2021-03-31'),
    (1253598,00025,'2021-03-01','2021-03-31'),
    (1253578,00025,'2021-04-01','2021-04-30'),
    (1253698,00025,'2021-04-01','2021-04-30'),
    (1254873,00025,'2021-04-01','2021-04-30'),
    (1253697,00259,'2021-02-01','2021-02-28'),
    (1253570,00259,'2021-02-01','2021-02-28'),
    (1254999,00037,'2021-01-01','2021-01-31'),
    (1252695,00037,'2021-02-01','2021-02-28'),
    (1254889,00037,'2021-05-01','2021-06-30')
go
```

Comment: That is a well asked question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the [`dense_rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function:

```
select ProjectId, StartDate, EndDate
  , dense_rank() over (partition by ProjectId order by StartDate)
from dbo.ProjectTable
order by ProjectId, StartDate, EndDate;
```